# How to run async task without need to await for result in current function/thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

Is there any chance to avoid waiting?
What we want for example:

```
async Task SomeTask()  
{  
   await ChildTask();

   //Then something we want to be done without waiting till "Child Task" finished  
   OtherWork();  
}  

async Task ChildTask()  
{  
   //some hard work   
}
```

Comment: Why use `Async` and `Await` in the first place then? Just run ChildTask as a normal task using `Task.Run()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Capture the `Task` and then await it after `OtherWork` is done:

```
async Task SomeTask()  
{  
   var childTask = ChildTask();

   //Then something we want to be done without waiting till "Child Task" finished  
   OtherWork();  
   await childTask;
}
```

Comment: I think this is not a good answer because here at the question it states that we dont need the result of the child task but in your solution the thread comes back to the await when the task is finished.

Answer (score 6):

You're not forced to *await* an asynchronous `Task`. If you don't `await` it, it's because you don't care if it finishes successfully or not (*fire and forget* approach).

If you do so, you shouldn't use the `async` keyword in your method/delegate signatures.

Comment: this is caused by the warning
`Warning CS1998 This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread`  this makes people think that the task wont be async if you don't use the await keyword